# Calcular o fatorial por passagem de referência

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou estudando ponteiros estou tentando fazer o cálculo de um fatorial de um numero, só que o resultado sai um valor totalmente diferente do esperado.
Aqui está o meu código

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void calulcafatorial(int num, int *fatorial);

int main(void)

{
     int num, *fatorial;
     scanf("%d", &num);
     calulcafatorial(num, &fatorial;
     return 0;
}

void calulcafatorial(int num, int *fatorial)
{
   int fat;
   for(fat = 1; *fatorial > 1; *fatorial--)
   {
      fat *= *fatorial;
   }
   printf("%d\n", fat);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cálculos [Fatoriais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatorial) envolvem [Números Muito Grandes](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_muito_grandes), e isso deve ser levado em consideração pois na prática, a memória disponível é [sempre finita](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing_que_sempre_para).

Códigos mais robustos são capazes de filtrar as entradas que produzam saídas "incalculáveis" devido as limitações da memória da máquina.

Levando o seu raciocínio em consideração, podemos implementar uma função para cálculo fatorial capaz de retornar um erro caso a entrada seja inválida ou incalculável, por exemplo: `n < 0` ou `n > 20`.

O maior número capaz de ser armazenado em uma variável do tipo `unsigned long long` é `18.446.744.073.709.551.615`.

O fatorial de `20` pode ser perfeitamente armazenado em um `unsigned long long` pois:

`20! =  2.432.902.008.176.640.000 < 18.446.744.073.709.551.615`

Já o fatorial de `21` extrapola a capacidade de armazenamento de um `unsigned long long` pois:

`21! = 51.090.942.171.709.440.000 > 18.446.744.073.709.551.615`

Levando seu raciocínio em consideração, segue um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fatorial( int n, unsigned long long * f )
{
    /* Verifica se o calculo eh possivel*/
    if( n < 0 || n > 20 )
    {
        return -1;     /* retorna -1 em caso de erro */
    }

    *f = 1;

    while( n > 0 )
    {
        (*f) *= n;
        n--;
    }

    return 0; /* retorna 0 em caso de sucesso */
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int num = atoi(argv[1]);
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned long long fat = 0;

    ret = fatorial( num, &fat );

    if( ret < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Erro!\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    printf("%d! = %llu\n", num, fat );
    return 0;
}
```

Saídas:

```
$ ./fatorial 5
5! = 120

$ ./fatorial 10
10! = 3628800

$ ./fatorial 15
15! = 1307674368000

$ ./fatorial 20
20! = 2432902008176640000

$ ./fatorial 21
Erro!

$ ./fatorial -1
Erro!
```

Answer (score 9):

Vou responder o que importa já que o problema só existe por causa de outro problema.

Estude ponteiros do jeito certo. Este caso não é para usar ponteiros e por isso tudo fica confuso. Até dá para fazer funcionar assim, mas não será o certo.

Funcionar e certo são coisas distintas.
[image: Funciona, mas não está certo]

Assim funciona:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int calculafatorial(int num) {
    int fat = 1;
    while (num > 1) fat *= num--;
    return fat;
}

int main(void) {
    int num;
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d", calculafatorial(num));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/pwE4kX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lelcxiwb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/ReturnInsteadParameter.c).

Mantive o erro de sintaxe que permitia compilar, mas consertei o que impedia a compilação. Tirei a impressão da função porque ela calcula o fatorial e não calcula e imprime o fatorial.

É, eu sei, tirei o ponteiro que era a dúvida central, mas neste código o uso do ponteiro só serve para atrapalhar. Agora procure algo que precise de ponteiro para aprender certo. Ponteiro é difícil, só use quando realmente não tem solução melhor.